# Session Variables Not passing to another page

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have Two pages.

1. **registration.php**
2. **thank-you.php**

when user submits form in **`registration.php`** , he gets redirected to payment gateway page and after successful payment lands on **`thank-you.php`**.

I want to update mysql database when user lands on **`thank-you.php`** with using **`$_SESSION`**
But **`$_SESSION`** Variables are not carried to **`thank-you.php`**.

Undefined Index error / notice is seen.

Code in **`registration.php`** is :

```
<?php
 include ('db.php'); //contains session_start();

if($_POST['action']=="registration"){

     if(empty($_SESSION['3_letters_code'] ) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['3_letters_code'], $_POST['captcha_code']) != 0)
     {  
        $msg="The Validation Code Does Not Match !";

    }else{

      //database insert related code goes here......

 $qry=$estambha->webdreaminsert("table_name",$all_columns,$all_values,'','','');
       echo mysql_error();

      $member_id=mysql_insert_id();

      $_SESSION['reg_member_id']= $member_id;

      header (Location = 'http://url-to-payment-gateway-for-payment-with filedset-values');
 }
}
?>
```

This Form adds all form data in mysql database entered on registration page and gets redirected to payment url perfectly.

After successful payment on payment gateway site, user is being redirected to **`thank-you.php`** page on my website.

But **`$-SESSION`** variables and values are not getting fetched from **`registration.php`** to **`thank-you.php`** and so mysql database is not getting updated.

Code in **`thank-you.php`** is :

```
<?php
 include ('db.php'); //session_start() included in this file as said above

 $updateqry=mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `fees_paid` = 1 WHERE `reg_id` =".$_SESSION["reg_member_id"]);

 ?>
```

Help needed. Thank you in advance.

Editing and adding code of db.php

```
<?
session_start();
include("include/function.php");
   //=================================================================================
$estambha=new bsq();
$estambha->connect_db();
?>
```

Comment: make sure the session was started in all pages using sessions. check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: what version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: *"Undefined Index error / notice is seen"* - what is that exactly? which one?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have tried ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL); in thank-you.php ... no error seen. when tried print_r($_SESSION) - Undefined index notice seen. Secondly I have included db.php which contains session_start , till I need to add it on every page?

Comment: In `registration.php`, your `include (db.php)` should be `include ('db.php');`

Comment: Show `db.php` so we can be sure you dont do anything before starting the session

Comment: as I said, the session needs to be started inside all pages using sessions. if it hasn't been, it has to be done.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Actually it should be `include 'db.php';` the brackets are just noise

Comment: btw, you do have the semi-colon for this at the end, right? `include (db.php)` - edit: @RiggsFolly GMTA.... pretty close hehe that alone would have thrown a parse error. probably why your session is failing.

Comment: You should post your actual code, how are we supposed to know what is really there and what is not? Because this: `header (Location = 'http://url-to-p....`....

Comment: And why are you mixing database calls using your `$estambha` object and `mysql_*` functions? Do you even have a `mysql_*` connection?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried session start on all pages just now...but till no success... line with errors here in include('db.php'); are just typo mistakes in this question only. On my page , it is like include('db.php');

Comment: why negative vote for my question?

Comment: `header (Location = '` please consult a PHP tutorial on basic syntax. The answer to your question is probably that you have a load of syntax errors causing the page to stop running.

Comment: It should be `header("Location: http://...");`

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh... I am so fool...

site_root defined in include file is http://www.example.com and I was checking thankyou page with link http://example.com/thank-you.php

when I used http://www.example.com/thank-you.php , it worked